# HashSet returns true when contains the object no matter the contents changes or not

Tags: java, hashset

I know it may be a naive problem but I'm really in need of help!
When I use HashSet and used it within some function that at some point, the 
content char[][] may be changed. I want to use the HashSet to check whether or not it contains the value but every time it return true no matter the value changed or not.

for example:

```
HashSet<char[][]> visited = new HashSet<char[][]>();
char[][] board = Board.board // initialization;
visited.add(board);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
if(visited.contains(board)
System.out.println("Why");
}
```

Here is the problem! Each time it returns "true" no matter no the board changes its contents;

Anyone can help??

I saw the comments and thanks for replying. The char[][] board is a map and I want to find a path 
on the map. The "for" loop is actually the search algorithm which find path from 4 direction. So each time the contents of the board is going change and I want to shorten the duplicates. That's why I used hashset to store the paths or maps I already traveled.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a full example of code that doesn't do what you expected?  The example that you provided of doing the same thing 4 times and getting the same result 4 times doesn't really illustrate a problem :)

Comment: If you always test the same object, then why you expect a different result? Also, plain arrays are different and do not have the same hash code even if they have the same length and size.

Comment: I want to find path on a map, which is the "char[][] board" in the problem. I want to use hashset to avoid the duplicate paths or maps.

Comment: All `char[][]` objects are different, regardless of the data they contain.  If you want to implement a hashCode() and equals(Object), you have to wrap this class with your own implementation.

Comment: yes. but every time I make change of the contents but they all have the same name"board" and hashset added that "board". So no matter how I change board contents, hashset will always return true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashSet` internally uses the `hashCode` and `equals` methods to tell if two objects are equal.  For arrays, `hashCode` and `equals` don't look at the contents of the array.  Instead, they just produce a hash code based on the identity of the object, and two arrays compare equal if and only if they're the same object.  This means that if you put an array into a `HashSet` and then try looking up that array after changing the contents, it will always find it.

Another detail here is that you put the array into the `HashSet` and then change the contents of the array externally, since the array is an object, you're also changing the copy of the array you put into the `HashSet` in the first place!

To fix this, I'd suggest defining a wrapper class around the array and then overriding `equals` and `hashCode` to check for equality based on the contents of the array and to compute a hash code from the contents.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would also add that if the `char[][]` is a "map" of some sort that he use a higher-level data structure than an array to model it: perhaps even a `java.util.Map` implementation.

Comment: The thing is...even if I replace it with "map" as you suggested. The hashset will still return true since only the contents but the "pointer" is not changed..